# How to display Switch/Case in 2 drop down lists

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

I have a php file that contains switch/case which is in JSON I believe.
Please excuse me on my knowledge of php/ajax/json, really trying to learn this.

```
<?php
    switch($_GET['make']) {
        case "Acura":
            echo json_encode(array("MDX","RDX","RL","TL","TSX","ZDX")); 
            return;

        case "Audi":
            echo json_encode(array("A3","A4","A5","A6","A8","Q5","Q7","R8","S4","S5","S6","TT","TTS")); 
            return;
    } 
?>
```

This is the file I have, it has all makes/models. How would I go about creating a drop downlist that shows all makes,"Acura,"Audi",  then have a second dropdown that would populate with models. If I selected Acura, the second dropbox would show MDX, RDX, RL, TL, TSX, ZDX

http://whodateswhere.com/auto/
I have the dev site set-up here but it's not functional. How would I be able to make it work on my site?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#ajax_make_id').change(function(){
    $.get('model.php',{ make: $(this).html() }, function(data){
        $drop_down_data = get_options( $.parseJSON(data) ); 
        $('#ajax_model_id').html( options ); 
    }); 
}); 

function get_options( options_array )
{
    var options = ''; 
    for( var i in options_array )
         options += '<option value="'+ options_array[i] +'">' 
                    + options_array[i] +'</option>'; 
    return options; 
}
```

Comment: hi again Intersteller. I appreciate the help you have given me already.

Comment: I've conformed it to fit my script however, I believe my switch code is incorrect on line 2
    `switch($_GET['make']) {`
Is this correct? I'm really confused over this. Can I email you by chance?